# Problem in installing mysql2 in ubuntu 14.04 in virtual box

Tags: software-installation

When I run this command, I got this error

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a few mandatory packages for gem to work. Should be ...

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

and after that

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

will work.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381485/2920227).